# Sort Row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a problem in sorting the excel spreadsheet in a row that contain value in number+string format. I have a data in the following sequence

```
work10, work11, work12, work1 and work2
```

I want to sort the data into the following sequence:

```
 work1, work2, work10, work11 and work12
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your data is strings, it is sorted according to text sort order.  To sort as you want, either pad the numbers with leading zero's, or split into seperate components, sort on the number part then reassemble the strings